# Firestore security rules: get() returns different result than the expected one

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore collection of `usernames` where each individual username acts as a document id. Each individual document has two fields only - `uid` (the uid of the owner) and `createdAt`. Thats all. I want to write a security rue, where I say "You can delete username ony if you own it". So here is my security rule:

```
match /usernames/{username} {
      function userOwnsUsername() {
        let unused = debug("does user owns username?");
        let uid = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(username)).data.uid;
        return debug(request.auth.uid == uid);
      }    
      allow delete: if isUserAuthenticated() && userOwnsUsername();
    }
function isUserAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

When I remove the rule `userOwnsUsername` the operation is executed successfully. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `get()` when trying to read data from the document being accessed/updated. Try using [`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) instead:

```
match /usernames/{username} {
  function userOwnsUsername() {
    return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  }    
  allow delete: if isUserAuthenticated() && userOwnsUsername();
}
```